# Novice - Chess Journey

Tags: learning

Frst, some chess background about myself - which is **VERY** limited - I am 50 years old, a bachelor, whom recently retired from the financial sector. Which basically translates to **A LOT** of free time!

okay, I was first introduced to the chess society during the 80's. And, because my interests were financially motivated, I placed chess on the back-burner, with every intention to one day pick up the Royal Game once more. Fastforward 30 plus years, and here I am -back to square one [no pun intended]- So, my question is, where best to begin my chess journey? That is, literature, technology, teachers, and/or online chess site recommendations?

Comment: The best place to begin is up in the left hand corner of this screen. Next to where it says "StackExchange" there is a magnifying glass icon and next to that it says "Search on Chess". Click on "Search on Chess", type in "Novice" and hit return. That will bring up a long list of related questions. It should always be the first thing you do before posting a question which may have been asked before because such a question WILL be closed as a duplicate.